# Remote SVN Manager for Windows

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN management, and I haven't (in the least) learned command-line SVN management. Is there any software for Windows that I could use to visually manage a **remote** SVN repository? I am looking for one that does **not** come bundled with an SVN server, and, preferably, is free of charge.

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is the best for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is a good choice:

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/